# Mapping multiple circle markers in a single layer with ipyleaflet and jupyter

Tags: python, leaflet, jupyter-notebook

How do I show multiple circle markers with ipyleaflet in jupyter?  I want to add them all as **one layer** (not individual layers) and I **do not** want to use the MarkerCluster class.  The documenation only references adding a single marker per layer - I tried: (using locations instead of location as referenced by the docs)

```
marker = CircleMarker(locations=[(172.7, -42.8),(172.7,-42.7)],
                          radius = 10,
                          color = "red",
                          fill_color = "red"
                         )
```

But that just got me one red circle in the middle of the map.  I can create a whole a list of circle makers and put them into a MarkerCluster but I don't really want to use this feature.  I just want small circles/points at the co-ordinates, in one layer.

```
df1 = map_df.set_geometry([Point(feature.coords[:][0][:2]) for feature in map_df['geometry']])
marker_list = []
for feature in df1['geometry']:
    marker = CircleMarker(location=(feature.coords[0][1],feature.coords[0][0]),
                         radius = 1,
                          color = "red",
                          fill_color = "red"
                         )
    marker_list.append(marker)

marker_cluster = MarkerCluster(
    markers=(marker_list),
    name = 'first point'
)
```

I also tried plotting the geodataframe but I could not see how to specify a cirle marker?  It uses the default blue pin which is not useful when I have a number of points to map.

Comment: Try layer group: https://ipyleaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/layer_group.html

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly

Comment: The url has been updated to this one: https://ipyleaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layers/layer_group.html